# VBA to split multi-line text in a excel cell into separate rows and keeping adjacent cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Please see the attach image which shows my data and expected data after running the macro,

- I would like to split the multi line cell in column B and listed in separate rows and removed text from first space. This values will be called as SESE_ID and should have the RULE from column C for each SESE_ID from the same row.
- If there is more than one prefix in column A separated by a comma or space-comma, then repeat the above values for each prefix.

Please someone help me in the macro...

1. Attached 1st image is the sample source:

[image: Sample Source Data Image]

2. And following is the macro:

```
    Sub Complete_sepy_load_macro()
    Dim ws, s1, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim rw, rw2, rw3, col1, count1, w, x, y, z, cw As Integer
    Dim text1 As String
    Dim xwalk As String
    Dim TOSes As Variant

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name = "CMC_SEPY_SE_PYMT" Then Sheets("CMC_SEPY_SE_PYMT").Delete
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set s2 = ActiveSheet
    g = s2.Name
    Sheets.Add.Name = "CMC_SEPY_SE_PYMT"

    Set s1 = Sheets("CMC_SEPY_SE_PYMT")

    s1.Cells(1, 1) = "SEPY_PFX"
    s1.Cells(1, 2) = "SEPY_EFF_DT"
    s1.Cells(1, 3) = "SESE_ID"
    s1.Cells(1, 4) = "SEPY_TERM_DT"
    s1.Cells(1, 5) = "SESE_RULE"
    s1.Cells(1, 6) = "SEPY_EXP_CAT"
    s1.Cells(1, 7) = "SEPY_ACCT_CAT"
    s1.Cells(1, 8) = "SEPY_OPTS"
    s1.Cells(1, 9) = "SESE_RULE_ALT"
    s1.Cells(1, 10) = "SESE_RULE_ALT_COND"
    s1.Cells(1, 11) = "SEPY_LOCK_TOKEN"
    s1.Cells(1, 12) = "ATXR_SOURCE_ID"
    s1.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    s1.Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    s1.Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("F:F").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("G:G").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("I:I").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("J:J").NumberFormat = "@"
    s1.Range("K:K").NumberFormat = "0"
    s1.Range("L:L").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"


    rw2 = 2

    x = 1
    y = 1
    z = 1
    'service id column
    Do
        y = y + 1
    Loop Until s2.Cells(1, y) = "Service ID"

    'Rule column
    Do
        w = w + 1
    Loop Until Left(s2.Cells(1, w), 4) = "Rule"

    'Crosswalk column
    Do
        cw = cw + 1
    Loop Until Left(s2.Cells(1, cw).Value, 9) = "Crosswalk"

    'Alt rule column (location derived from rule column)
    'counts # of cells between "rule" and "alt rule", used as precedent for rest of "alt rule" cells
    ar = w
    Do
        ar = ar + 1
    Loop Until Left(s2.Cells(1, ar).Value, 3) = "Alt"
    ar = ar - w

    'prefix row
    Do
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until s2.Cells(x, w)  ""

    'first service id row
    Do
        z = z + 1
    Loop Until s2.Cells(z, y)  ""

            'change rw = z + 2 to rw = z, was skipping first two rows
            For rw = z To s2.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
                If s2.Cells(rw, y)  "" Then

                    If InStr(1, s2.Cells(rw, y), Chr(10))  0 Then
                        TOSes = Split(s2.Cells(rw, y).Value, Chr(10)) 'Chr(10) is the "new line" character
                        count1 = 0
                        Do
                            If Trim(TOSes(count1))  "" Then
                                For col1 = w To s2.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                                    If Left(s2.Cells(1, col1), 4) = "Rule" Then
                                        If InStr(1, TOSes(count1), " ") > 0 Then
                                            s1.Cells(rw2, 3) = Trim(Left(TOSes(count1), InStr(1, TOSes(count1), " ")))  'sese
                                        Else
                                            s1.Cells(rw2, 3) = TOSes(count1)
                                        End If

                                        s1.Cells(rw2, 1) = s2.Cells(x, col1) 'prefix
                                        s1.Cells(rw2, 5) = s2.Cells(rw, col1) 'rule
                                        'use crosswalk service id to populate alt rule
                                        If s2.Cells(rw, cw).Value  "" Then
                                            If xwalk = "" Then
                                                Match = False
                                                xwalk = Trim(s2.Cells(rw, cw)) & " "
                                                rwcw = z
                                                Do
                                                    If InStr(1, s2.Cells(rwcw, y).Value, xwalk, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                                        'obtain rule and write to alt rule column of current row
                                                        s2.Cells(rw, col1).Offset(0, ar).Value = s2.Cells(rwcw, w).Value
                                                        Match = True
                                                    End If
                                                    rwcw = rwcw + 1
                                                Loop Until Match = True
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                        s1.Cells(rw2, 9) = s2.Cells(rw, col1).Offset(0, ar) 'alt rule
                                        s1.Cells(rw2, 7) = "TBD" 'cac
                                        s1.Cells(rw2, 13) = s2.Name 'file

                                         rw2 = rw2 + 1
                                    End If
                                    xwalk = ""
                                Next col1
                            End If
                            count1 = count1 + 1
                        Loop Until count1 = UBound(TOSes) + 1
                    Else
                        For col1 = w To s2.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                            If Left(s2.Cells(1, col1), 4) = "Rule" Then
                                If InStr(1, s2.Cells(rw, y), " ") > 0 Then
                                    s1.Cells(rw2, 3) = Trim(Left(s2.Cells(rw, y), 4))  'sese
                                Else
                                    s1.Cells(rw2, 3) = s2.Cells(rw, y)
                                End If

                                s1.Cells(rw2, 1) = s2.Cells(x, col1) 'prefix
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 5) = s2.Cells(rw, col1) 'rule
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 9) = s2.Cells(rw, col1).Offset(0, ar) 'alt rule
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 7) = "TBD" 'cac
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 13) = s2.Name 'file

                                rw2 = rw2 + 1
                            End If
                        Next col1
                    End If
                ElseIf s2.Cells(rw, y) = "" And Trim(s2.Cells(rw, w))  "" Then
                    If Len(s2.Cells(rw, 1)) >= 10 Then
                        text1 = Left(s2.Cells(rw, 1), 10) & " |row: " & rw 'sese
                    Else
                        text1 = s2.Cells(rw, 1) & " row: " & rw 'sese
                    End If
                        For col1 = w To s2.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                            If Left(s2.Cells(1, col1), 4) = "Rule" Then
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 3) = text1 'sese
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 1) = s2.Cells(x, col1) 'prefix
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 5) = s2.Cells(rw, col1) 'rule
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 9) = s2.Cells(rw, col1).Offset(0, ar) 'alt rule
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 7) = "TBD" 'cac
                                s1.Cells(rw2, 13) = s2.Name 'file

                                rw2 = rw2 + 1
                            End If
                        Next col1
                End If
            Next


        For rw3 = 2 To s1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            s1.Cells(rw3, 2) = "1/1/2009"
            s1.Cells(rw3, 4) = "12/31/9999"
            s1.Cells(rw3, 11) = 1
            s1.Cells(rw3, 12) = "1/1/1753"
        Next rw3
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim wss, wsSepy, wsSID As Worksheet 'SID = Serivce ID Spreadsheet
        Dim sepyRow, sepyCol, acctCol, sidSeseCol, sidAcctCol, j As Long
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim cellRange As Range
        Dim topRow As Range
        Dim sepySese As String

        MsgBox "All set, make sure there is no #N/A in SESE_RULE column"
        End Sub
```

3. Below image is the output I got:
   [image]
4. Problem: If you see the source data, I have SEPY_PFX in column A. I wanted every row to be repeated for each SEPY. Currently my code gave me RULE as SEPY_PFX, I am still working on it BUT it will be glad if someone help me on this quickly, it is already going above my head.

Comment: @pnuts I don't understand the link you posted with regard to this thread

Comment: @pnuts OIC.  I didn't realize he had posted elsewhere.  I found this problem interesting though, especially with regard to copying the font colors

Comment: @pnuts Well, hopefully he will respond with clarifications, and his code will indicate the direction he is taking.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am looking for a macro to get this, I am quite new in macro, I am trying from my end too.

Comment: So far I have reached this...I will add more as an answer, I can't add an attachment here.

Comment: Maybe [you can do this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3180-excel-multiline-cell-to-rows-columns.html) straightforward in Excel, without VBA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will work on the first example you posted to give the output you wanted:

Original Source:

[image]

Original Results:

[image]

It works by using **Class** and **Collections**, creating each entry one at a time, and then putting it together for the results.

I use arrays to collect and output the data, because this will work much faster.  In your original you had some font coloring, which I have carried over.

You should be able to adapt it to your real data, but, if you cannot, I suggest you post a "sanitized" copy of your original data, with the correct columns and so forth, on some file sharing web site such as DropBox, OneDrive, etc; and post a link here so we can see the "real stuff"

With regard to the use of classes, please see  [Chip Pearson's web site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)

Also, please read the comments in the code for explanations and suggestions.

First insert a Class Module, ReNAME it **cOfcCode** and paste the code below into it:

```
'Will need to add properties for the additional columns

Option Explicit

Private pSEPY As String
Private pFontColor As Long
Private pSESE As String
Private pRule As String

Public Property Get SEPY() As String
    SEPY = pSEPY
End Property
Public Property Let SEPY(Value As String)
    pSEPY = Value
End Property

Public Property Get FontColor() As Long
    FontColor = pFontColor
End Property
Public Property Let FontColor(Value As Long)
    pFontColor = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Rule() As String
    Rule = pRule
End Property
Public Property Let Rule(Value As String)
    pRule = Value
End Property

Public Property Get SESE() As String
    SESE = pSESE
End Property
Public Property Let SESE(Value As String)
    pSESE = Value
End Property
```

Then, in a regular module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReformatData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim vSEPY As Variant, vSESE As Variant
    Dim cOC As cOfcCode
    Dim colOC As Collection
    Dim lRGB As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long

'Change Sheet references as needed
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet3")

'Assuming Data is in Columns A:C
With wsSrc
    Set rSrc = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
End With
Set rRes = wsRes.Range("A1")

vSrc = rSrc
Set colOC = New Collection  'Collection of each "to be" row
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)

    'Split SEPY_PFX into relevant parts
    vSEPY = Split(vSrc(I, 1), ",")
    For J = 0 To UBound(vSEPY)

        'Get the font color from the original cell
        With rSrc(I, 1)
            lRGB = .Characters(InStr(1, .Value, vSEPY(J), vbTextCompare), 1).Font.Color
        End With

        'Split SESE_ID into relevant parts
        vSESE = Split(vSrc(I, 2), vbLf)

        'Iterate through each SESE_ID, picking up the SEPY_PFX, and RULE
        For K = 0 To UBound(vSESE)
            Set cOC = New cOfcCode

            'Will need to adjust for the extra columns
            With cOC
                .FontColor = lRGB
                .Rule = vSrc(I, 3)
                .SEPY = vSEPY(J)
                .SESE = vSESE(K)
                colOC.Add cOC '<-- ADD to the collection
            End With
        Next K
    Next J
Next I

'Put together the Results
ReDim vRes(0 To colOC.Count, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

'Copy the column headings from the source
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 2)
    vRes(0, I) = vSrc(1, I)
Next I

'Will need to add entries for the other columns
For I = 1 To colOC.Count
    With colOC(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .SEPY
        vRes(I, 2) = .SESE
        vRes(I, 3) = .Rule
    End With
Next I

'Clear the results worksheet and write the results
wsRes.Cells.Clear
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
rRes = vRes

'Add the correct font color and format
For I = 1 To colOC.Count
    rRes.Rows(I + 1).Font.Color = colOC(I).FontColor
Next I

With rRes.Rows(1)
    .Font.Bold = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

rRes.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Make the changes to the Worksheet references in the code (only need to do that at the beginning of the regular module.

Try this first on your original example, so you can see how it works, then add in the extra columns and processing to the Class and the Collection, or post back here with more details

Comment: You guys are great...Thank you!!! I am a beginner in VBA and I am learning a lot from this website. Hopefully someday I will be able to answer other's questions too.

Comment: And my apology for not telling everything upfront, the sample data what I gave is one piece of it where I stuck, now with this help I am able to prepare the actual data where it has many reference and loop, I just did not want to give everything in this forum. Thanks you guys..

Comment: This is a solid bit of code to not get any upvotes!  I guess it's the nature of SO that short and universally useful stuff goes to the top.  Excellent write up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the original data is in worksheet "DATA", and worksheet "Expected Output" which is used to store processed data , exist already.

Your code will be:　Operation of most lines are explained by comments (right of "'")

```
Sub processData()
Dim oWS As Worksheet, pWS As Worksheet
Dim oRow As Long, pRow As Long
Dim splitMultiLine As String, splitPerfix As String
Dim c As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim prefixes As Variant, lines As Variant
Dim dataACol As String, dataBCol As String, dataCCol As String


Set oWS = Worksheets("DATA") 'original data
Set pWS = Worksheets("Expected Output") 'processed data

'Copy title row
For c = 1 To 3
  pWS.Cells(1, c) = oWS.Cells(1, c)
Next c

oRow = 2 ' row of oWS
pRow = 2 ' row of pWS

With oWS
  While (.Cells(oRow, 1) <> "") 'Loop while A colmn has value
    dataACol = .Cells(oRow, 1) 'data in A column
    dataBCol = .Cells(oRow, 2) 'data in B column
    dataCCol = .Cells(oRow, 3) 'data in C colum

    prefixes = Split(dataACol, ",") ' split prefixes by comma
    lines = Split(dataBCol, Chr(10)) ' split multi lines in a cell by newline (Char(10))

    For i = LBound(prefixes) To UBound(prefixes)
      For j = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
        pWS.Cells(pRow, 1) = Trim(prefixes(i)) ' A column of output
        k = InStr(lines(j), " ")
        pWS.Cells(pRow, 2) = Left(lines(j), k - 1) ' B column of output
        pWS.Cells(pRow, 3) = dataCCol ' C column of output
        pRow = pRow + 1
      Next j
    Next i
    oRow = oRow + 1
  Wend
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. However I am getting a bug in this below line, it says _invalid procedure call or argument_ **pWS.Cells(pRow, 2) = Left(lines(j), k - 1) ' B column of output**

Comment: Well, well. That cord works fine on my Excel 2013. What kind of Excel are you using?