# Split a cell into two rows while duplicating the rest of the data?

Tags: excel, split, duplicates

I'm pulling data from our database to send out to a 3rd party according to their template. I need to send guardian information, with each person having their own row. Our database has the guardian information with a "/" and then details by each ID #. I need to split the data according to the Guardian cell while duplicating everything else.

[image]

Can this be done in Excel without any special add ons? All help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425208/vba-split-cell-values-into-multiple-rows-and-keep-other-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439099/how-to-split-a-single-cell-into-multiple-rows-and-add-another-row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776914/vba-to-split-multi-line-text-in-a-excel-cell-into-separate-rows-and-keeping-adja

Comment: Is this a one-time requirement?  You need to split the existing rows once, or do you need to automatically split them when future data data is entered? Either way, no add-ons required. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Scott Craner linked to the correct answer using a VBA (which was new to me) but was exactly what I needed.

```
Sub splitByColB()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B999999").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.row > 1
        ar = Split(r.value, "/")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Image shown here.]
Cell `N1` is the delimiter. In this case a slash.

```
Helper:=SUM(K1,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,$N$1,"")))+1
```

You must fill the above formula one row more.
Then change `K2` to 1 manually because there is a slash in `B1`.

```
A11:=a1
```

Fill this formula to the right.

```
A12:=LOOKUP(ROW(1:1),$K:$K,A:A)&""
```

Fill this formula to the right and down.

```
B12:=MID($N$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$K:$K,B:B)&$N$1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($N$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$K:$K,B:B)&$N$1,$N$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$K:$K)))+1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($N$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$K:$K,B:B)&$N$1,$N$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$K:$K)+1))-FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($N$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$K:$K,B:B)&$N$1,$N$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$K:$K)))-1)&""
```

Fill down.

Bug:

Numbers will be converted to Text. Of course you can remove the &"" at the end of the formula, but blank cells will be filled with 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved me a shitload of time and headaches